# How to get range from a string in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like `SL45NU2154-60`

Now I want an array from this string like

```
SL45NU2154
SL45NU2155
SL45NU2156
SL45NU2157
SL45NU2158
SL45NU2159
SL45NU2160
```

How can I do this using jquery or javascript.

What I have tried.
first I split this string with `'-'` and found an array with `SL45NU2154` and `60`. Now I don't know how to make an array by looping or anyway. 
Here is my code

```
var str = 'SL45NU2154-60';
var str_arr = str.split("-");
alert(str_arr);
```

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet Please see the update question. I added my code what I have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your jquery

```
  var main="SL45NU2154-60";
var arr=main.split('-');
var fnal=parseInt(arr[1]);
var last2=parseInt(arr[0].substr('-2'));
var firstval=arr[0].slice(0,-2);
for(var i=last2;i <= fnal;i++)
{
 alert(firstval+""+i); 
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/n4eRH/1/)

Answer (score 1):

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sQ6w3/1/)

this will handle any alpha numeric characters inputted by the user, knowing that letters comes first before numbers.

```
var str = "SL452154-60";
var target = str.replace(str.match(/[a-zA-Z][^\d]/g),'');
var alpha = str.match(/[a-zA-Z][^\d]/g);
var fromTo = target.split('-');
var from = fromTo[0];
var to = fromTo[1];

var res = [];

for(var i=parseInt(from);
        i<= parseInt((from.substring(0,(from.length - to.length))) + fromTo[1]);
        i++)
{
res[res.length] = alpha + i;
}

alert(res)


<br>
```

**NOTE**: you can try changing the string to, for example : `"KG123125-60"`

Answer (score 0):

If you know that format is always kept, where you have at the end `XX-XX`, then you could try splitting with a regex to extract the parts and build a range.

First create a helper to fill in a range within a minimum and a maximum:

```
var range = function(m, n) {
  var out = []
  for (var i=m; i<=n; i++) {
    out.push(i)
  }
  return out
}
```

Then split the string to find out the range min and max values:

```
var str = 'SL452154-60'
var parts = str.split(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/)
```

Then create the range with the helper:

```
var ran = range(+parts[1], +parts[2]) // `+` makes sure they're numbers
```

Finally you can map each number in the range array to generate an array of strings:

```
var result = ran.map(function(x){return parts[0]+x})
//^ ["SL452154", "SL452155", "SL452156", "SL452157",
//   "SL452158", "SL452159", "SL452160"]
```

Answer (score 0):

`function a()
{`

```
var str = 'SL45NU2154-60';
var str_arr = str.split("-");
var len =0;
var storage="";
for(var i=str.length; i>=0; i--)
{
var res = str_arr[0].substring(i-1,i );

    if(!isNaN(res))
    {
        storage=storage+res;
    }
    else
    {
    break;
    }
}
//after this you got 4512 the opposite order of 2154 now reverse it
alert(storage.length);
var storage2="";
for(var i=storage.length; i>=0; i--)
{
var res = storage.substring(i-1,i );


        storage2=storage2+res;

}
alert(storage2);
//after this long conversation you now retrieve the 2154 
var len2 = str_arr[1].length;
var num2= str_arr[1];
var storage3 = storage2.substring(len2,storage2.length);

while(storage3<=num2)
{
    var total =parseInt(storage3)+1;
    //now add this number to the inputed number

}`
```

`}`

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRange(str){
    var parms=str.split('-');
    var start=parms[0];
    var end=parms[1];
    var doStart = start.substr(start.length - end.length);
    var pre=start.match(/[a-zA-Z][^\d]/g);
    var post = start.replace(str.match(/[a-zA-Z][^\d]/g),'');
    var res=[];
    start=parseInt(doStart,10);
    for(i=start,j=0;i<=end;i++,j++){
        res[j]=pre+post;
        post+=i;
        }
    return res;
    }




console.log(getRange("SL452154-60"));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var string="SL45NU2154-60";
var string = string.split('-');
var len = string[1].length;
initial = string[0].substr(-len);
parseInt(initial);
var fixedString = string[0].slice(0, string[0].length - len);
var a= new Array();
for(var i=initial; i <= parseInt(string[1]);i++){
    a.push(fixedString+i);
}
console.log(a);
```